# MPMoviePlayerController is in fullscreen mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

How do I determine whether `MPMoviePlayerController` is in full screen mode or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Apple's doco](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Use the MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification and
>   MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification notifications to detect
>   changes to and from fullscreen mode.

There is also a [fullscreen property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW57):

> A Boolean that indicates whether the movie player is in full-screen mode.